# ActiveRecord where query not working for attributes but select method is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, aasm

What explains this bizarre behavior? `work_state` is an state attribute derived from `aasm` gem, but I don't have trouble querying this with other models...

```
MaintenanceOrder.all.select { |m| m.work_state == "pending_work" }.size
=> 235
MaintenanceOrder.all.pluck(:work_state).select { |s| s == "pending_work" }.size
=> 235
MaintenanceOrder.last.work_state
=> "pending_work"

# so at this point... obviously there are MaintenanceOrders with work_state of "pending_work", and yet...

MaintenanceOrder.where(work_state:"pending_work").size
=> 0
```

As requested, this is the state set up

```
aasm(:work, column: "work_state",no_direct_assignment: true )  do
    state :pending_work, initial: true
    state :in_progress
    state :complete
    state :not_fixable
```

What's further odd is that queries work with OTHER states, i.e., this works:

```
MaintenanceOrder.where(work_state:"in_progress").size
=> 12
```

Also the SQL looks fine when I do `log_level = :debug`

```
MaintenanceOrder.where(work_state:"pending_work").size
   (15.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "maintenance_orders"  WHERE "maintenance_orders"."work_state" = 'pending_work'
=> 0
```

Update on oddities.. is there a giant gotcha here that I don't know??? Another model has a SIMILAR issue. FWIW the states with issues, `"pending_work"` above and `"pending_start"` below both are the beginning, initial default states...

```
Item.where(aasm_state: "pending_start").size
=> 19 # so at least some records are found, but not all of them
Item.all.pluck(:aasm_state).select { |s| s == "pending_start" }.size
=> 19
Item.all.select { |i| i.aasm_state == "pending_start"}.size
=> 94

# If I delve a little deeper.... it appears that the where query is just picking up the last few records... even though there's no size limit indicated?? in other words

where_ids = Item.where(aasm_state: "pending_start").map(&:id).sort
select_ids = Item.all.select { |i| i.aasm_state == "pending_start"}.map { |i| i.id }.sort

where_ids == select_ids.last(19)
=> true
```

Comment: Could you add the ``aasm`` definition from the model to your question?

Comment: Maybe its a **Enum** field so pass the integer value with where query.

Comment: @mlockerd posted

Comment: @code_aks alas it's not, in fact, other states are query-able

Comment: Just turn on `development` mode OR change log level to `config.log_level = :debug` to watch actual SQL generated for your console commands. Than inspect your DB. And you will get the answer.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk how do I turn on `development` mode? is it possible for production heroku app's pg db?

Comment: I can't reproduce in any of my AASM models, which I realise isn't super helpful. If you are running a console via ``heroku run`` you ought to be able to run ``ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = :debug`` to turn on SQL logging for that session. I'd also suggest running ``MaintenanceOrder.all.pluck(:work_state)`` to see if you have any suspect states in the database.

Comment: @rmlockerd ok i added `pluck` results, SO WEIRD... in `MaintenanceOrder` where  the `where` query returns nothing, `pluck` has same result as `select`. In the `Item` where the `where` query returns a partial set, `pluck` has same result as `where` (i.e., the partial set)

Comment: ``WHERE "maintenance_orders"."aasm_state" = 'pending_work'`` -- that's why you get 0 results; it is using ``aasm_state`` as the query column rather than ``work_state``. I don't understand that at all at the moment, but I think that's a big clue.

Comment: @rmlockerd  wait no sorry that's cuz i copied and typed wrong =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this... but wildly unsatisfactorily because it's just a plain mystery to me. The solution was different for the 2 different cases above. It seems like the root causes of the 2 were different, but it also seems like in neither case will I ever know the reason why...

**MaintenanceOrder model issue**

I did a lot of `git diffs` here to check my sanity. Literally... I turned `config.log_level = :debug` in `production.rb` then pushed the app to production. I monitored that the correct SQL statements were being used in the query (as I copied over into the above question). Then I reset `config.log_level = :info` and pushed to production. Then suddenly it worked.

No other changes.. suddenly `MaintenanceOrder.where(work_state:"pending_work").size` returned the correct value

**Item model issue**

Here, the fact that the `where` query was finding some but not all records, and that the subset it was finding was only recent, made me wonder maaaaaybe the old records... were... saved... improperly somehow? I had after all just done a big database migration.

So I ran `Item.all.select {|i| i.aasm_state == "pending_start"}.each { |i| i.update_column(:aasm_state,"pending_start") }`, and that fixed the problem

Comment: I did a typo in my comment. **Then** inspect your DB. You had to do it to clear it all. For example, query like `Item.group(:aasm_state).count` could show you a lot of things like typos or NULLs in the `aasm_state` and so on. If you'd still have the strange things, you could go to DB directly through console client.